# Do I need to remove the adhesive from peel & stick vinyl when putting hardwood with rosin paper?

Tags: floor, adhesive, hardwood, vinyl

I am removing peel and stick vinyl from plywood and will be putting nailed 3/4 in  hardwood in its place. Do I need to get all of the adhesive up or is it ok to just put my rosin paper or other underlayment down, then nail in my 3/4 in oak pieces? I am having problems getting the adhesive up and be not sticky.

Comment: How lumpy is it? A photo would be great.